# Unit test private and static methods in java

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, static, private

I'm writing unit tests for an app of mine and as good practice I try to make all methods in my classes as private as possible, so I may end up with classes with mostly private methods, few public ones and sometimes some calls to static methods (either of my other classes or to some TextUtils, etc)

I would like to know how to get to test all of my classes trying to rely only on Mockito and JUnit since Robolectric and Powermockito seem to stretch the boundaries of what should be done in unit testing. Should I disregard all private and static methods along with public methods that by chance call some static or private ones? or how?

Comment: These are two very distinct questions. Generally, private members should be tested indirectly, through the public interface, and static methods are usually testable standalone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the private methods in the class you're testing should be called by some public/protected/package private method; otherwise they're unused code. So, just concentrate on testing this public API that's visible to the "client code" of your app. The internals (private methods) will get tested/covered as a side effect because they actually implement the public contract that the API specifies.

Testing implementation details (private methods) directly would make the tests harder to maintain and the code-under-test more difficult to refactor.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I actually thought of that but it sounded somehow wrong in my head since if I have a public method that also calls a private one and I test the former to catch them both it feels that I am not anymore testing a "unit" but an "ensemble"

Comment: The "unit" in unit testing is not always so simple to define. But in general, I think it makes things easier in the long run if you focus on testing the public interface of your class and keep implementation details nicely encapsulated. If you feel that the private methods are doing things that you'd like to test specifically, perhaps that implies that this logic should be modeled in its own class which could then be (publicly) unit tested separately.

Comment: @kioli *"it feels that I am not anymore testing a "unit" but an "ensemble""* **-** The question here is *what is a **unit**?* I like the definition of Roy Osherove: *A unit is a bunch of code that has the same reason to change.* This means a unit can be a single method or a couple of classes.

Comment: thank you very much, I'll try to steer into this approach for the whole bunch of tests I've already in place

Answer (score 3):

**Note: this is general information only, as your question does not provide code to comment on.**

Since private methods are not generally accessible outside of the class (reflection is another matter altogether) and are typically there to provide functionality to your public and protected methods, your unit test just needs to test your public and protected methods. If you choose your test data carefully, you should be able to exercise most/all of the code.

You can use Mockito to mock out any dependencies that the class under test requires. You use expectations (`Mockito.when(...).thenReturn(...)` or `Mockito.verify(mockedClass).method(...)`) to mock external functionality or to check that the class under test makes outgoing calls as expected.

You can use assertions to check that methods being tested return appropriate values.

**Keep in mind however,** a detailed unit test with a high code coverage has a high chance of breaking the first time you try to change the internal implementation of the class under test. It's a balancing act, and you need to find the right level of coverage, while minimizing how brittle the test is.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I commented on the answer above why I thought it may have been wrong to skip the direct private method testing